# Empty select but append new values on user choice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this SELECT element:

```
<select name="user_type" id="user_type">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Choice one ...</option>
    <option value="natural">Natural Person</option>
    <option value="company">Company</option>
    <option value="personal">Personal Company</option>
</select>
```

And then I have this other SELECT:

```
<select name="id_type" id="id_type"></select>
```

I need to append some values from array based on user choice from the first SELECT so I did this:

```
$('.user_type, #user_type').on('change', function() {
    selected = $(this).find('option:selected').val()
    show = selected != 0 ? true : false;
    $(".personal_data").toggle(show);

    var natural = ["V", "E", "P"];
    var company = ["J", "G"];
    var personal = ["V", "E"];

    $('.id_type, #id_type').empty();
});
```

You'll notice arrays has the same names as first select option values, the idea is to append the array values any time the first select is changed. Otuput ex: user choice is `company` second select will be:

```
<select name="id_type" id="id_type">
    <option value="J">J</option>
    <option value="G">G</option>
</select>
```

How I do that? I mean how do I move in array and append the result on the SELECT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to put all available options into a structure which you can then access using `selected`.

example:

```
$('.user_type, #user_type').on('change', function () {
    selected = $(this).find('option:selected').val()
    show = selected != 0 ? true : false;
    $("#id_type").toggle(show);

    var options = {
        'natural':  ["V", "E", "P"],
        'company':  ["J", "G"],
        'personal': ["V", "E"]
    };

    // Empty the select first
    $('.id_type, #id_type').empty();

    // Are there options available for this selection?
    if (options[selected]) {
        // Append each available option
        for (var i = 0; i < options[selected].length; i++) {
            var opt = options[selected][i];
            $('#id_type').append('<option value="' +opt + '">'+opt+'</option>');
        }
    }
});
```

[working jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jkvz0w56/)